# How to add more synonims to a SOLR SE?

Tags: java, lucene, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

My application is related to health care, so I would like to have queries that use **"heart"** to also bring results that include **"cardiac"**
That is just an example, I have many more synonyms I need to load.

How does SOLR can be taught about those synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the SOLR documentation, you'll want to create a SynonymFilter on a Field in your schema, and then define a synonyms.txt file to define all your synonyms, formatting of the file is detailed best in the docs so I won't go into it here.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters